# How does the switch statement work without the break

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm using the switch statement without the breaks and it seems it defaults to the last case even if it does not meet the condition.

```
function getLetter(s) {
    let letter;
    // Write your code here
    console.log(s[0])
    switch (s[0]){
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
          letter = 'A';
         
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
        case 'd':
        case 'f':
        case 'g':
           letter = 'B';
         
        case 'h':
        case 'j':
        case 'k':
        case 'l':
        case 'm':
            letter = 'C';
       
        case 'n':
        case 'p':
        case 'q':
        case 'r':
        case 's':
        case 't':
        case 'v':
        case 'w':
        case 'x':
        case 'y':
        case 'z':
            letter ='D';  
        }  
  return letter;
    
}
console.log(getLetter('abcj'));
```

I expected the code to return A since it does not match any of the other cases statements but instead it returned D which does not match the expression. I did add the "break" and it worked as expected but I'm curious as to why what I had above did not work.

Comment: Without a `break` it falls through to the next `case` and keeps going till it hits a `break` or reaches the end. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#breaking_and_fall-through

Comment: just google fallthrough in switch case, you will get some more knowledge

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement continues to function without the break statement, but all cases following the first match are also processed. This implies that until a break or the end of the switch block is reached, each case is assessed and performed in succession if there is no break statement.